# Why .getMinutes() output as :0 instead of :00 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The .getMinutes() method only outputs one integer ‘0’ instead of two integers ‘00’. Why does it do this and is there a simpler way to fix this?

Example:

```
        var dateDue = new Date("Fri Apr 22 2022 18:00:00");
        dateDue.getMinutes();   //Expected output: 18:00, got 18:0 instead?
```

For now I have been using if statement validation to add 0 whenever the minutes .Length returns as only being one character long instead of two.

```
        //Minutes display validation for dateDue
        var minutesDue = dateDue.getMinutes();
        if (minutesDue.Length === 1) {
        minutesDue = parseInt(dateDue.getMinutes()) + "0";
```

Coding language: JavaScript (vanilla) 
Skill level: Beginner 
Editor: Visual Studio Code 
OS: Windows 7

Comment: _"instead of two integers ‘00’"_ - Why should it do that? `.getMinutes()` returns a number. And there's no such thing as `00` as a number.

Comment: `parseInt(dateDue.getMinutes())` - parsing an integer doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: _"For now I have been using if statement..."_ -> [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: Numbers don't have a length. Your `if` test should be `minutesDue < 10`. Also it's `length` in JavaScript when appropriate, not `Length`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toLocaleTimeString` method with some options for padding and even more styling. This one does AM/PM automatically for you.

```js
const time = new Date("Fri Apr 22 2022 18:00:00").toLocaleTimeString('default', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
console.log(time) // '06:00 PM'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could answer half the question if it helps to start thinking process. To put :00 for seconds. You need a loop which checks the condition, if seconds less than 9. If that's the case concatenate 0 to secs.

Comment: This is incorrect. Just `toString()` it and then use padStart.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateDue = new Date("Fri Apr 22 2022 18:00:00");
if (dateDue.getMinutes() < 10) {
       var getMinutes= '0' + dateDue.getMinutes();
   }
```